# how to process arrow, pageUp, pageDown keys in C or C++ on linux

Tags: c++, c, linux

How do I get the key codes so I can process arrow, pageUp, pageDown, etc, keys using simple C or C++?

I can get the regular keys, I do not know how to get these special keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux based systems follow the UNIX tradition, in the sense that those keys are special and their values depend on the terminal settings.

This is so, because in the old days each UNIX system had a complete different type of keyboard. As such it is somehow complex to be able to write generic code to handle those special keys.

The best way is to make use of a terminal handling library, like curses or its successor ncurses.

Here you can get a nice introduction about keyboard usage,

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/keys.html

Comment: thank you for the replay and the link to an example. It was very useful

Comment: `s/each UNIX system/each UNIX terminal/`. In the old days*, UNIX systems didn't have keyboards. Terminals attached to UNIX systems had keyboards. (*In my case, old=PDP-11/44, new=VAX 11-780).

Answer (score 2):

Ncurses should be able to handle that. There is lots of tutorials out there